# want to insert data from one table into another in php?

Tags: php, database, insert

I have two tables `users` and `bid_details`, both have `id` column which is a primary key for `users`.

`bid_id` is primary key for `bid_details`.

`bid_details(bid_id,id,bid_price,start_date,end_date)`

`users(id,fname,lname,username,email_id...........)`

I provided text box to enter bid price. `bid_id` is set to autoincrement. After user enters amount in text box I want to insert all the values in `bid_details`. But how can I get the value of `id` from `users` and insert into `bid_details`?

Comment: add your table structure and tried code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understands the question well, you want the user to insert a product details
and you want to save his/her id in the details table.
You can do this simply using session (by saving user-id in a session variable)

```
$_SESSION['id']=$id;
```

This [link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_sessions.asp) has session details

Comment: @ShankyRedkar Glad that I can help. please click the right symbol near the answer, in order to mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can either send user_id through url in GET method or send as hidden  value through POST method.

Comment: Bad, really bad idea!  A much better approach is to store the user id in the session during the login process.

Comment: Consider if this is admin section and admin is adding details for different users else we can use SESSION

Comment: This is definitely not the case, judging from the question.  He's got a user placing a bid.